# Redirect a page if change happen in its url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have this page that is daynamic with URL parameters:

```
/artandculture/details.php?articleid=28208&parentid=1&catid=166
```

and i want that if user change in URL then it redirect to main URL,e.g any change in URL then redirect to:

```
/artandculture/details.php?articleid=28208&parentid=1&catid=166
```

Is there solution with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Need more info: what do you mean by change? can you give example URL from which you want to redirect? **|** As per as I understand, you want to redirect if user change in parameter's names OR some miss syntax after `details.php`, coz GET values(mostly integer) can be change as these for to create dynamic page. **AND** url before **?** not easily known for change coz you will have some other pages-urls in your website.

Comment: suppose user(visitor of site) change the URL to this:     /artandculture/details.php  then i want that it redirect to main URL :     /artandculture/details.php?articleid=28208&parentid=1&catid=166

Comment: If user just enters `/artandculture/details.php` in browser should it always be redirected to `/artandculture/details.php?articleid=28208&parentid=1&catid=166`?

Comment: @anubhava,yes and no,yes,for this article it must redirect to this URL ,but no,because there are lot of articles and each one has its own URL parameters it must redirect to its URL.

Comment: Then how do you think web server will know where to redirect when URL it receives is just `/artandculture/details.php`?

Comment: I don't know ,and my question is for solving this,and let me set forth my question in a wide range,please see this URL :http://www.beytoote.com/news/cultural-news/enews419.html   you see that any change in URL cause that it redirect to specific page,how it can be done by htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

After your confirmation, Try this solution with htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/artandculture/details\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^articleid=[0-9]+&parentid=[0-9]+&catid=[0-9]+$
RewriteRule .* /artandculture/details.php?articleid=28208&parentid=1&catid=166 [L,NC,R=307]
```

---

`RewriteCond` will check that is requested uri is your perticuler page then next will excute. And next `RewriteCond` will check if GET parameters are not there OR in wrong format then change the URL to main PAGE.

Removing `,R=307` from last rule will not redirect(change the address in browser), this will just display the main page with user changed URL.

Comment: yes,you are right for understanding of my question but the code does not work and not redirect,please note that i gave only an example ,for any change in that url or urls like that it must redirect.

Comment: on my htaccess file at top there is:      'RewriteEngine on'   and why you have put the tag(#) before the codes, my codes has not (#) .

Comment: @Kaveh: Sorry for error and Thanks for notifying (#) error. Actually the second condition should check the `QUERY_STRING` only, that was the error. I have edited the answer, check that.

Comment: You can change second condition to meet your redirection requirement. The first condition is only to ensure it should not redirect for other pages like _about-us.php_ coz on that case second condition will always true and third will redirect.

Comment: No  problem,thanks,but please note that for this article it must redirect to this URL and there are lot of articles so for each one it must redirect to its own URL,with your code all redirect to this URL.

Comment: @Kaveh: in that case you need to write RULES for each article... there is no other solution with .htaccess unless and until you have a specific pattern In article's name(folder-name). | **If you have dynamic articles THEN** I'll suggest do it by your code(PHP/C#/Java whatever you are using)... First redirect all request to your one page, and by coding detect wrong URLs(by regular expressions) and redirect to specific page.